# $\pi (x) = -1 + \pi(\sqrt x) + \sum \mu (d)\lfloor \frac {x}{d}\rfloor$,

Tags: number-theory

Sorry about the title i didn't know what to call this other than "analytic number theory"

I am asked to show that $\pi (x) = -1 + \pi(\sqrt x) + \sum \mu (d)\lfloor \frac {x}{d}\rfloor$, where the sum is over all d for which ever prime factor is less or equal to $\sqrt x $

The furthest right hand part of the equation looks like a mobius inversion but im not sure how to do it over root x and the rest i am completely lost on.

Comment: "Analytic number theory" is the part where you use analytic functions of a complex variable, like Riemann zeta. Everything else is called "elementary number theory", though most of it is very far from being elementary in the usual sense of the word. And no, that's not Moebius inversion, though it's expressing the same principle of inclusion/exclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be [Legendre’s formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914994/legendres-formula?rq=1) for computing $\pi(x)$:
$$
\pi(x)=-1+\pi(\sqrt{x})+\lfloor x \rfloor-\sum_{p_i\le a}\left\lfloor \dfrac{ x }{(p_i)}\right\rfloor+\sum_{p_i<p_j\le a}\left\lfloor\dfrac{ x}{(p_ip_j)}\right\rfloor-\sum_{p_i<p_j<p_k\le a}\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{(p_ip_jp_k)}\right\rfloor+\dots
$$
This is proved there.

Comment: thanks for the post i actually did get the argument already thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is true. Take $x=25$.

$\pi(x)=9$, $\pi(\sqrt{x})=3$.

The relevant $d$s are $2, 3, 5$ together with their square-free multiples, that is $6, 10, 15, 30$. The factor $\lfloor \frac {x}{d}\rfloor$ kills the participation of $15$ and $30$.

For the rest we get $$9=-1+3+(-12-8-5+4+2)$$

which is wrong, right?

Comment: @Faust Yes, the numbers 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30 are those only made of the primes 2, 3, 5, and also square free otherwise $\mu$ is $0$ and there is no contribution.

Comment: You forgot 1! That's +25 And the floor of 25/15 is one

Comment: @Faust Silly me :)